# How To share Images in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have Added the image in drawable folder and then I displayed it on layout file and also added a button and after for it i have added on click method, now I want to share images to whatsapps and fb so how can I send it... Please help me....

Comment: You should try the official document. https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to understand what you want, because of the missing code. But I will try to help you.

I found this solution:

```
public void shareImage() {

final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");

final File photoFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "image.jpg");

shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
}
```

Just add `shareImage()` to the `OnClickListener` of your `ImageView`.

> If you want more details check [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents), where I got the code from.

If you don't want to send an image from your gallery, then replace `photoFile` with the file wich you want to send.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, Actually, I tested this code but nothing happens. I had searched on the  Google but all available source code, not helpful.

Comment: Suppose that, If  I have added the image to drawable folder in studio, then I addded button and in onclick method i have added share intent. So how do I send it.